# Beveled shadow border

Tags: javascript, css, border

I am trying to do a **beveled shadow border** in CSS.

Now it works that i have a several images (up left corner, down left, right corner etc...). It is very bad solution of this problem and I beleive a better solution in CSS or JS is possible.

With buttons it doesnt work.

The most important thing, *it has to be responsive*

In css I tried outset, but it does not work exactly how I want.

[image]

**EXAMPLE IN IMAGE: [example how it should looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRCxM.jpg)**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with multiple `box-shadow` properties, for example:

```
box-shadow:
  -1px 1px 0px #ccc,
  -2px 2px 0px #ccc,
  -3px 3px 0px #ccc,
  -4px 4px 0px #ccc,
  -5px 5px 0px #ccc,
  -6px 6px 0px #ccc,
  -7px 7px 0px #ccc,
  -8px 8px 0px #ccc,
  -9px 9px 0px #ccc,
  -10px 10px 0px #ccc
}
```

Demo example - https://jsfiddle.net/bztexp0z/

```css
body { background-color:#28434E; padding:50px; }

.box { 
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#fff; 

box-shadow:
  -1px 1px 0px #ccc,
  -2px 2px 0px #ccc,
  -3px 3px 0px #ccc,
  -4px 4px 0px #ccc,
  -5px 5px 0px #ccc,
  -6px 6px 0px #ccc,
  -7px 7px 0px #ccc,
  -8px 8px 0px #ccc,
  -9px 9px 0px #ccc,
  -10px 10px 0px #ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

You can reduce the thickness by just having `-1` to `-4` for example.

Comment: So I tried it. It works on 50% percent. Because I need a different of color left border and bottom border -> example image

Answer (score 0):

Finally I work this out. I used pseudo selector :before and :after with skew transformation.

Solution is here: https://gist.github.com/rihot/d4530492dfdbec05db1421fce1d248e6